# How do I replace underscores with spaces in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make my ggplots nicer. This includes replacing the underscores in variables names with spaces.

I have tried the gsub function, but then I will have to change all the variable names in my code as well. I am thus looking for a function within the ggplot() function that replaces underscores with spaces.

This will have to be done for a total of 25 graphs. I could do it manually with fct_recode, but I am hoping for a smarter fix.

```
df_gap_gender %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x = key, y = share, fill = hh_member_gender)) + 
     geom_col(position = position_dodge()) + 
     coord_flip() + labs(x = "") + 
     scale_fill_manual(values = c("#194220", "#2EAB4A"))
```

The graph I want to change variables names on

[image]

Comment: `tmp <- df_gap_gender; tmp$key <- gsub("\\.", "_", tmp$key)`

Comment: For this we need at least the head of your dataframe: use `dput(head(df_gap_gender))`

Comment: `scale_x_discrete(labels=function(x) gsub("_", " ", x, fixed=TRUE))`

Comment: Thanks guys - an internal gsub function did the trick!